# In c++, how do we read in 3 lines of number sepearted by white spaces and enter them into a vector?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read 3 `string` separately from user input, it all contains numbers separated by white spaces for example "1 2 3". I will read in three lines and store these number in a vector of integer

However the program stop reading the `string` after I enter "1 2 3"

I'm expecting to enter "1 2 3" first, then enter "4 5 7", then " 8 9 0", and add all these number to the vector.

the print out look like this

```
Enter the puzzle
1 2 3
123
```

I'm expecting something like this

```
Enter the puzzle
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
1234567890
```

Where could the problem be?
I tried the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


int main(){
  vector<int> arr;
  cout << "Enter the puzzle" << endl;
  string line1;
  string line2;
  string line3;
  cin >> line1;
  cin >> line2;
  cin >> line3;


  istringstream is(line1);
  int num;
  while(is>>num){
    arr.push_back(num);
  }
  istringstream is2(line2);
  while(is2>>num){
    arr.push_back(num);
  }

  istringstream is3(line3);
  while(is3>>num){
    arr.push_back(num);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
    cout << arr[i];
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Does the problem exist because of `isstringstream`?

Comment: Can you explain in English how your program is supposed to know how many lines there are?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read file line by line using ifstream in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c)

Comment: A very good first step is often to immediately print your inputs and see what they really are.

Comment: Why do you need to read line by line? The entire file is numbers separated by whitespace.

Comment: When you use the "input" operator `>>`  to read strings, it reads *space-delimited* "words". That means `cin >> line1` will read only the first `1` into `line1`.

Comment: The problem (with the information known to us) could be solved with only a *single* statement: `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ""));`

Comment: You probably have to separate the strings at the witespaces so you can check the nine numbers seperatly with istringstream

Answer (score 0):

`cin` will read only one number.

Instead of using:

```
cin >> line1;
cin >> line2;
cin >> line3;
```

use:

```
getline(cin, line1);
getline(cin, line2);
getline(cin, line3);
```

for more [look here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)